# Is keeping all logic in local EJBs is good?

Tags: oop, ejb, ejb-3.0

I have some business logic in stateless EJB, but the logic is too complex and too big for one EJB. So I can see the following things to do here:

1) Extract the logic into some helper classes and instantiate them in EJB, so EJB will be like a facade for all the business logic.
Disadvantages that will be here: EJB has a lot of injected resources (e.g. queues, connectionFactory, other EJB's), so I have to pass those in a constructor to helper classes. Maybe not that convenient, but doable.

2). Create more local stateless EJBs with business logic and inject.
Disadvantages that will be here: I'm not sure if having a lot of local EJB's actually affects the performance of the whole application. Probably somehow it does: it has to add it to pool, instantiate etc.

I'm using EJB3.0 and WebLogic as a container.

What would u say will be a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Though the problem is too broad, I would prefer approach 2. It brings in maintainability(in case you have to do some work with a new functionality, you have to modify the api of helper class). BTW, why didn't you consider breaking your business logic to small methods in the same bean?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The solution was to go with second step, as it is easier to inject than to create classes with long constructors. I didn't want to have big classes, that's why I didn't consider breaking business logic to smaller methods in the same bean

Comment: Typically, the EJBs act as proxies to the java classes delegating the functionality. That gives flexibility in testing without EJBs in picture; also easier to move away from EJBs should the need arise